# Removing duplicate extension files on Java

Tags: java, string, file-io

Having a folder with the following files

```
myoutput.pdf
hello.pdf.pdf
byebye.txt
hey.txt.txt
```

How can I remove the extension of ONLY the files with a duplicated extension? In the example there are only pdf and txt, but in the real example can be any type of extension.

I got this far:

```
String dir = "C:/Users/test";

File[] files = new File(dir).listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

But I don't know how can I now detected the ones with "duplicated extension" and rename it to a "single extension"

My desired output would be:

```
myoutput.pdf
hello.pdf
byebye.txt
hey.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
file.getName().replaceAll("(\\.\\w+)\\1+$", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDIK33/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `(\\.\\w+)` - Group 1 capturing a dot and 1 or more word chars (`\\w+` might be replaced with `[^.]+` to match 1 or more chars other than a dot)
- `\\1+` - one or more occurrences of the same value captured in Group 1
- `$` - end of string.

The replacement pattern is just the backreference to Group 1 (`$1`) to only have 1 single occurrence of the extension.

Comment: Thanks, that prints me the correct filename, but how can I now "rename" the file? I tried `file.renameTo(file.getName().replaceAll("(\\.\\w+)\\1+$", "$1"));` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the code as below:

```
if (file.isFile()) {
    String newFileName = file.getName().replaceAll("(\\.\\w+)\\1+$", "$1");
    file.renameTo(new File(file.getParent() + "/" +newFileName));
}
```